# Google Analytics check for "Unique Visitors" PHP

Tags: google-analytics, ip

Is the aformentioned's check for "Unique Visitors" just a simple IP check?

Or is something a bit more mysterious and powerful (this is Google we're on about)

Comment: Did I answer your question or is there anything else you would like to know?

Comment: Well you answered the first part of the question, but didnt really expand on other methods they use

Comment: @Z0q that's not at all true. It's publicly available information. Very little about how Google Analytics calculates things is secret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IP address is not at all a consideration for Google Analytics calculations of unique visitors; think about what happens if you take your laptop to a coffee shop and use their WiFi; should you really be counted as a different visitor? Or what if your ISP uses dynamic IP addresses?

The unique visitor metric is [based solely](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33087) on the existence of a particular cookie, the `__utma` cookie (the one set to expire in 2038).

From the [Official Google Analytics Help Center](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33087):

> Unique Visitors represents the number
>   of unduplicated (counted only once)
>   visitors to your website over the
>   course of a specified time period. A
>   Unique Visitor is determined using
>   cookies.

Because of this, 'Unique Visitor' is an inherently flawed metric. It can be skewed by cookie deletion, browser changes, and multiple machines. In other words, because I use 3 browsers across 2 laptops, plus my phone, to Stackoverflow's Google Analytics account, I'm 7 unique visitors. And that's before factoring in how often I clear my cookies.

Comment: Has anyone had luck in getting around this?  We have plenty of uniques data that we'd like to send with the GA request, but I think they're wedded to cookies.  Our users are mostly on older mobile phones without cookies, so our GA unique visitors data is way off.

Answer (score 1):

It's using cookies among (I guess) other mechanisms. you can have a look at [this article](http://www.morevisibility.com/analyticsblog/from-__utma-to-__utmz-google-analytics-cookies.html) to see how the cookies sent by Google Analytics are used.